# On IntelliJ Idea, what are GroupID and ArtifactID and how do I use them?

Tags: maven

Me and my team are creating a new project on IntelliJ Idea and it asks for GroupID and ArtifactID. We would like to know the purpose of GroupID and ArtifactID and how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: These are [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) properties. See the linked duplicates, and [the official Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html)

Comment: and they're neither java, nor intellij related

Comment: @Stultuske Eh, I think it's fair to say it's Java-related. While Maven isn't strictly a Java tool, I've never seen anyone use it for anything else.

Comment: @Michael groupId and artifactId are pure maven. sure, they are used a lot in Java projects, then again, so is english. I don't consider the difference between "their, they're and there" to be Java relatedd either.